# Authenticating users from active directory on an android app using LDAP

Tags: android, authentication, active-directory, oauth-2.0, ldap

I want to authenticate users in an android application using credentials from active directory from my company server.I have the LDAP path and the domain name.Is there any way to fetch the credentials from the active directory via an android app and authenticate the user? If yes then how?

Comment: No one has the reply? :-O

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-android) project that uses Azure AD and the ADAL library for authenticating the user and calling a web API using OAuth 2.0 access tokens.